# My CSS doesn't work now that I used a <!--nextpage--> to split my page

Tags: html, css, genesis

This is what my CSS looks like on the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
<style>
p.addresscenter {
    background-color: none;
color: #333;
font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
line-height: 1.2;
margin: 0;  
    text-align: center;
    white-space: pre;
}
p.endtagbold {
    background-color: none;
color: #000000;
font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
line-height: 1.2;
margin: 0;  
    padding-top:16px;
}
p.hoursofoperationcenter {
    background-color: none;
color: #333;
font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
line-height: 1.3;
margin: 0; 
    text-align: center;
    white-space: pre;
}
p.infop {
    background-color: none;
color: #OOOOOO;
font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
line-height: 1.5;
margin: 0;  
    padding-bottom:30px;
}
p.infostextbox {
    background-color: none;
color: #OOOOOO;
font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 550;
    font-style: normal;
line-height: 1.5;
margin: 0;  
    padding-bottom:16px;
}
p.topmenu {
    background-color: none;
font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
line-height: 1.4;
margin: 0;  
    text-align: center;  

}
p.towncounty {
    background-color: none;
color: #000000;
font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 700;
    font-style: italic;
line-height: 1.4;
margin: 0;  
    padding-top:16px;
}


 </style>
   </head>
   <body>


<p class="topmenu">Text with id tags here.</p>
```

There is a set of columns here made with these tags

```
 <div class="one-half first">Text</div>
 <div class="one-half"> Text </div>
```

Then there is more text which is formulated by `<p class=""></p>` and then finally the `<!--nextpage-->` attribute occurs somewhere in the middle.

After the `<!--nextpage-->` tag I have more text with `<p class=""></p>`

The entire page ends with

```
</body>
    </html>
```

On my other pages that are not split the css shows up fine.  For whatever reason the css is not showing up on page 2 after the `<!--nextpage-->` .  What do I have to do to make sure the css shows up before and after the `<!--nextpage-->` attribute.

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand everything well, but You should try to place `<!--nextpage-->` between the tags, and not inside of them.

For example:

```
<p>asdasd</p><!--nextpage--><p>asdasd</p>
```

Is ok, while:

```
<p>asdasd<!--nextpage-->asdasdasd</p>
```

is not ok. I hope this is the case, if not, please do not downvote and update You question with full code. Then I will try to update my answer.

---

Few more words. When You click next page, then the paragraph element has started on the page before. So on the actual page there is no paragraph start, but only: `asdasdasd</p>` which is causing problems, and is not a valid html.

Best regards.

Comment: I believe a broken tag is the likely cause of this problem as well.